# Setting properties defined in a super class in the initialiser

Tags: ios, objective-c, initializer

From what I learned a general rule of thumb setting values in `init` is a matter of using the ivars directly.

For example

```
@interface CustomClass

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;

@end
```

and then:

```
- (instancetype)initWithName:(NSString *)name
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _name = name;
    }

    return self;
}
```

Now so far so good. I'm interested in a slightly different case. Let's say you're subclassing a UIView and in the initialiser you want to assign a background color to that subclass. Here, the property `backgroundColor` is defined in the parent class. My question is: Is it bad style or potentially wrong to use `self` in the initialiser? Would it be better to set the background color somewhere else?

```
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Comment: I guess it is fine what you have done there.

Comment: You have no other option. You can't directly access `_background` (if there even is such an ivar in the base class).

Comment: As an aside, you probably want to use `(nonatomic,copy)` instead of `(nonatomic,strong)`,  Your class should **own** `name`, instead of pointing to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it is perfectly fine what you are doing there. At that point, after calling `super.init`, the `self` exists, and you can use it (you are calling `return self`, too, so why would other references to `self` be wrong?).